# javascript: get keys containing duplicate data in an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I have a javascript associative array. It will be populated dynamically.

I want to find the keys which will contain the duplicate data/values.

For simplicity, it will look like this.

```
var p =   { };
 p =
    {
        "p1": "value1",
        "p2": "value2",
        "p3": "value3",
        "p4": "value2",
        "p5": "value3",
        "p6": "value5"
    };
```

How can i do this.

Here's the js fiddle.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZTMF/2/)

Is there other way than using hasOwnProperty?

Any ideas to make this work?

Comment: You cannot have two `p5` keys!  The second one will override the first one.  It's like it was never even there.

Comment: P.S. This isn't an "associative array", it's an "object".

Comment: Sorry fixed the duplicate key issue.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` won't help you find duplicate values.  That checks to see if an object has a certain "key".

Comment: What was your issue or what is your issue?

Comment: @plalx i want to find keys which contains duplicate data as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat you are right, i just put in there to try to figure how can i go about finding the keys etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly tighter version of @RocketHazmat's solution:

```
var values = {},
    dupes = [],
    key,
    val;
for (key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        val = p[key];
        if (values[val]) dupes.push(key);
        else values[val] = true;
    }
}
```

This just gives you a list of keys with dupes. (Note - the first instance of a dupe value isn't considered a dupe here.)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, really appreciate your help. I added the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/xVvj2/

Comment: You could also put the assignment inside the brackets: `if (values[val = p[key]])`, even shorter.

Answer (score 3):

```
var p =
    {
        "p1": "value1",
        "p2": "value2",
        "p3": "value3",
        "p4": "value2",
        "p5": "value3",
        "p6": "value5"
    };

var q = {};
var keys = Object.keys(p);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var currentKey = keys[i];
    var newKey = p[currentKey];
    if (q[newKey] === undefined){
        q[newKey] = [];
    }
    q[newKey].push(currentKey);
}
```

This will get you an object looking something like:

```
{
  "value1": ["p1"],
  "value2": ["p2","p4"],
  "value3": ["p3","p5"],
  "value5": ["p6"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I can think of is to loop through your current object, and mark each value you see.  When you see a value again, mark that key.

```
var tmp = {};
for(var i in p){
    var val = p[i];

    // Have we seen this value before?
    if(!tmp.hasOwnProperty(val)){
        // Mark the value as seen for the first time
        tmp[val] = []; // 0 duplicates
    }
    else{
        // We've seen it before, save the duplicate key
        tmp[val].push(i);
    }
}

// Print out values and their duplicate keys
for(var i in tmp){
    var keys = tmp[i];

    // Are there any duplicates?
    if(keys.length){
        alert(i + ' has multiple keys: '+keys.join(', '));
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bjRDK/

Comment: I am torn whether to mark your answer as accepted one or nrabinowitz. Yours uses two loops while nrabinowitz uses one. But you answered first. All i want in the end is the keys, but if i remove the i + ' has multiple keys: ' part in the end i get the keys etc . His solution also gives dupes as well etc. Try to be fair here,

Comment: @Nomad: Pick whichever one you like better / works better for you.  It shouldn't matter who posted first.  The point of accepting an answer is to pick which you think is "best", shouldn't matter who posted and when :-)

Comment: I did. Thank you so much for your time and help, I really really appreciate it. I liked the other solution better, hope you wont mind. Once again thanks a lot.